# Tool for File Recover | Deleted Files Recovery

Tags: files, data-recovery

Advise me please some recovery tools for File Recover | Deleted Files Recovery | Damaged Files

Comment: It depends on the nature of your backup...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with deleted files is that they no longer have inodes and a lot of the data about the filename and how they're linked together is lost. It's not like in windows where the filesystem just renames the file.

There are ways to do it, you can follow some of the guides here:

http://e2undel.sourceforge.net/recovery-howto.html

They show you some of the tools which use heuristics and guessing to put data back together.

Comment: good, but i need some tool with friendly GUI

Comment: just link for tools

Comment: The process is so dangerous and specialised that there are no friendly tools that do it. This is a serious job and it's kind of expected that you would read the documentation and understand what's going on. Otherwise you won't understand the results (because they are not always what you might expect)

Comment: there are a few tools for windows (that recover linux files) but they only work on ext3, and I've not been successful.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to try is the Trash bin.

Go to Places -> Home Folder

Then click on Trash

If the file is there right click and then select Restore.

If this does not help try following the official ubuntu data recovery instructions here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: I mean some software)

Comment: The official instructions tell you the best software for the task.

Answer (score 2):

[Autopsy](http://www.sleuthkit.org/autopsy/) and the SleuthKit tools are relatively user friendly for this purpose, at least in relation to some other tools.