# Is mount filesystem as /tmp delete filesystem content?

Tags: 20.04, mount, filesystem, tmp

I made a bad mistake .I mounted a /dev/sda2 as /tmp folder in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I think this filesystem /dev/sda2 is a part of logical partition.

lsblk result before mount:

[image: lsblk result before mount]

then Ubuntu won't boot again.

Is /dev/sda2 content has been deleted? if not how can i undo mount command

Comment: You have to look if there is anything left on /dev/sda2 by mounting it again (but not again at /tmp !)

Comment: In the future, instead of mounting inside `/tmp` mount inside `/mnt`. Files inside of `/tmp` usually get blown away on boot.

Comment: @frederic are you suggest mount /dev/sda2 to another directory?
but as I have showing in lsblk result this filesystem was not mounted to any directory.

Comment: Before you can see what is on /dev/sda2, you have to mount it. Chances are indeed that it has been erased if it has been mounted to /tmp. The /tmp folder is deleted between boots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `/tmp` is [periodically deleted](https://askubuntu.com/a/983848/558158). Therefore, there is a chance that the contents of your `/dev/sda2` has been deleted.

You can inspect the contents of your `/dev/sda2` partition by mounting it, obviously not again under a critical system folder. The easiest way will be to click the icon of the drive in your file manager. From the terminal, you could temporarily mount under `/mnt` with the command

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

after which the command

```
ls /mnt
```

will show the contents. Again, if you persistently mounted the partition on `/tmp` and rebooted, the contents of `/dev/sda2` may be gone. If this are personal data, it is hoped that you have a backup. Otherwise, your only hope is [file recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11298/tool-for-file-recover-deleted-files-recovery), but that is a difficult process where full recovery is not always possible.

Comment: The answer you linked is pretty old. [Newer Ubuntu might behave differently](https://askubuntu.com/a/857154/867283) depending on the configuration.